# Thread C++: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I'm new in c++ , and I want to utilize thread to call BM class method from main class.I have main.cpp ,BM.h and BM.cpp files

some part of my code in main.cpp

```
string id = res->getString("nct_id");
char txt[temp_size];
char pat[5];
BM bm ;
thread Sam(&BM::search,&bm, txt, pat ,id); // use thread calls class method
```

BM.h

```
void search( char *txt,  char *pat , string id);
```

BM.cpp

```
void BM::search( char *txt,  char *pat ,string id)
```

I have error:

```
No matching function for call to
'std::thread::thread(void (BM::*)(char*, char*, std::string), BM*, char [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)temp_size) + -1)) + 1)], char [5], std::string&)'
```

please  help me

thank you

Comment: Provide declaration of `txt`, `pat` and `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using a non-standard language extension, namely, variable-length arrays (VLAs). These arrays don't work well with templates. It is recommended to ditch all character arrays and all VLAs, and use std:string and std::vector throughout.

If you cannot, use this simple workaround:

```
thread Sam(&BM::search,&bm, &txt[0], pat ,id);
```